I recently switched from PSW to skilled worker visa. my husband didn't get visa for 5 years completely. He got 10 days less visa than me. y it is so?
Main applicant visa - 18 Feb 2024- 18 Feb 2029
Dependent visa - 28 Feb 2024- 18 Feb 2029

Presumably because your visa was processed/issued first, and your dependent’s visa was processed/issued after yours.
